# Error al llamar base de datos sqlite

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, xml

estoy aprendiendo a crear una app, en específico, obtener un dato desde una bd ya creada y setearlo en un text. Seguí varios tutoriales pero me da un error (el código en sí no muestra ningún error, pero la app se cae).

Ésta es la clase de la base de datos:

```
public class ManejadorBaseDeDatos extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "imcEmbar.db";

private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

private static ManejadorBaseDeDatos sInstance = null;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public ManejadorBaseDeDatos() {
    super(MainActivity.activity, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    try {
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static ManejadorBaseDeDatos instance() {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new ManejadorBaseDeDatos();
    }
    return sInstance;
}


private void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {

        db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db_Read.close();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error");
        }
    }
}

public boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = MainActivity.activity.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}


public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
    return mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}
```

Ésta es la clase dónde quiero llamar a la bd:

```
public class Imc_Ema extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnCalcular;
EditText txtIngresoSemanas;
EditText txtResultado;
ManejadorBaseDeDatos manejadorBD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imc_adultos);

    manejadorBD = ManejadorBaseDeDatos.instance();
    btnCalcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
    txtIngresoSemanas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIngresoSemanas);

    btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtResultado.setText(null);
            Double semanas = Double.valueOf(txtIngresoSemanas.getText().toString());
            Cursor cursor = manejadorBD.select("SELECT NormaMin FROM imcEmb WHERE Codigo_producto = '" + semanas + "' ");
            String consulta = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NormaMin"));
            txtResultado.setText(consulta);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Y éste es el error:

```
12-04 22:07:59.433 13916-13916/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp, PID: 13916
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp/com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp.Imc_Ema}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:109)
                                                   at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:129)
                                                   at com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp.ManejadorBaseDeDatos.<init>(ManejadorBaseDeDatos.java:0)
                                                   at com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp.ManejadorBaseDeDatos.instance(ManejadorBaseDeDatos.java:46)
                                                   at com.xxkuakxxgmail.knowyourchamp.Imc_Ema.onCreate(Imc_Ema.java:25)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: No soy conocedor de programación para Android, pero parece que `MainActivity.activity` está evaluando a null en el constructor de `ManejadorBaseDeDatos`.

Comment: @ChristoferParra, debes definir valor a la variable activity que usa la clase ManejadorBaseDeDatos, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error esta especificado como :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object
>   reference

Estas tratatando de llamar el método [getapplicationinfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) desde una instancia nula de Context. Debido a que estas realizando incorrectamente una instanciación de `ManejadorBaseDeDatos`.

**El problema es que no estas definiendo el contexto, en este caso debes definir el valor de la variable `activity`, que es usada dentro de la clase `ManejadorBaseDeDatos`**, se debe realizar de esta forma:

```
public class Imc_Ema extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnCalcular;
EditText txtIngresoSemanas;
EditText txtResultado;

//*Agregar variable activity
public static Activity activity;
ManejadorBaseDeDatos manejadorBD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imc_adultos);

    //* Importante definir esta variable, que es usada dentro de la clase ManejadorBaseDeDatos. 
    activity = this;         
    manejadorBD = ManejadorBaseDeDatos.instance();

    btnCalcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
    txtIngresoSemanas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIngresoSemanas);

    btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtResultado.setText(null);
            Double semanas = Double.valueOf(txtIngresoSemanas.getText().toString());
            Cursor cursor = manejadorBD.select("SELECT NormaMin FROM imcEmb WHERE Codigo_producto = '" + semanas + "' ");
            String consulta = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NormaMin"));
            txtResultado.setText(consulta);

          //*Siempre cerrar cursor al terminar de obtener datos!
          cursor.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te dejo un código funcional. Puedes agregar los algoritmos necesarios para implementar el resto de las sentencias SQL

```
public class VentasRepository extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "cerveceria";
private static String DATABASE_TABLE = "Ventas";
private SQLiteDatabase sql = null;

public VentasRepository(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("
            + "id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
            + "idUsuarios TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + "idCervezas TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + "idModalidades TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + "cantidad TEXT NOT NULL "
            + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public List<Ventas> findAll() {
        List<Ventas> todos = new ArrayList<>();
        Reflexion reflexion = null;
        Ventas entidad = null;
    try {

        sql = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                entidad = new Ventas(); // Creando una clase vacia
                reflexion = new Reflexion<Ventas>(entidad); // Creando una reflexion para cada clase entidad nueva

                for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    reflexion.setValor(cursor.getColumnName(i),cursor.getString(i));//Almacenando valor para una sola entidad
                }

                todos.add(entidad);//Almacenando la entidad en una lista de entidades.

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(sql!=null) sql.close();
    }
    return todos;
}

}
```

Comment: Porque una base de datos "cerveceria", esto no tiene que ver con la pregunta. Por favor revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Solo era una muestra para base de datos en SQLite....yo la implemente para una cerveceria, el asunto seria que la adaptaras pero es la misma estructura.